# Controller to view data cannot pass

Tags: laravel

This is my controller code:

```
$id = Auth::user()->id;

$businessid = Bunk::where('bunkvendorid', $id)->first()->id;

$username = user::where('businessid', $businessid)->first()->name;

$useremail = user::where('businessid', $businessid)->first()->email;

$usermobile = user::where('businessid', $businessid)->first()->mobile;

$datas = [
    'username' => $username, 'useremail' => $useremail, 'usermobile' => $usermobile
];

return view('bunk.cashier')->with($datas);
```

This is my view file code:

```
@foreach ($datas as $data)
    <tr>
        <td>{{ $data->$username }}</td>
        
        <td>{{ $data->$useremail }}</td>
        
        <td>{{ $data->$usermobile }}</td>
    </tr>
@endforeach
```

**I am getting error**

> Undefined variable `$datas` (View: C:\Users\Gowtham\Desktop\blog2\resources\views\bunk\cashier.blade.php)

Comment: return view(''bunk.cashier'', compact('datas'));  Don't use $ sign here.

Comment: Did you tried, to print $datas, I mean like print_r($datas), to check the variable?

Comment: `{{ $data->$username }}` should be `{{ $data->username }}` (without the `$`). Same for the others in your view file

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You are sending an aray wth key values paires mean $datas contain keys like **username** **useremail** etc.
When you apply loop on this then in $data variable your keys vlaues exist.
You can simply use like this,

```
@foreach ($datas as $data)
<tr>
    <td>{{ $data }}</td>
    
    <td>{{ $data }}</td>
    
    <td>{{ $data }}</td>
</tr>
@endforeach
```

In first iteration data contain **username** then **useremail**, and phone soon.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need the $datas variable in your view. Simply access the variables in the $datas array like so:

```
{{$username}}
```